# mean-centering case

Tags: matrices, data-analysis

I have some data in matrix format, with one variable for every column. One categorical variable (column 2, say) specifies some feature of the remaining numerical variables. I want to remove the mean of all the numerical values that belong to one category of the forhmentioned categorical variable. That is to say, I want the mean of those values to be 0, whilst retaining all the information in the data. It is a kind of mean centering but for only a given set of values in the matrix, not single rows or single columns, which could be done by multiplying the data by the adequate centering matrix. What are some ways of performing this kind of matrix-manipulation to preprocess the data?

Comment: Can't you simply subtract the mean?

Comment: If I did that I will be obtaining a zero mean for all the data, but I want to have some values with mean zero while some others with mean not equal to zero.

Comment: Sorry, I mean subtract the mean of a given variable from each column

Comment: That should work in principle, although I am not sure that it wouldnt alter the data since I have not seen it in the literature.

Comment: That's the standard approach in [PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) for instance

Comment: And substracting the mean will work even if the values whose mean I want to be zero are in all the variables but only in certain rows??  for example: for each variable (columns), the values in rows 3,4,9 and 24 have a mean of x and must have a mean of zero. Substracting x to every value in the dataset will do the work?

Comment: And Is that a standard approach in PCA? I dont think I have a profound understanding of the method, but I recall that the data is standarized for every variable, not centered for certain values in each variable.

Comment: From the wiki page: *"Consider an ${\displaystyle n\times p}$ data matrix, X, with column-wise zero empirical mean (the sample mean of each column has been shifted to zero), where each of the n rows represents a different repetition of the experiment, and each of the p columns gives a particular kind of feature (say, the results from a particular sensor)."* So yes: each variable is shifted to be centered at zero, which is to say that each variable has its mean subtracted.

Comment: To accomplish what you want: for each column, subtract from each entry in the column the mean of the values in rows $3,4,9,$ and $24$ (of that particular column). So for each column, a different value is subtracted.

Comment: okay I'll try that. Thank you Ben!

Comment: Without losing important structure, we can modify any column so that a desired subset of its entries (rows) has a mean of $0$.

Comment: You're welcome.